# Creating a EJB3.1 + Portlet Project

Tags: java, ejb, cdi, portlet

I just want to create a Portlet and to use an EJB in this Portlet.

Iam using JBoss 7.1 and Liferay 6.2.

I create a EJB project and a liferay plugin project.

I just want to call a method from the EJB, shown here:

```
@Local
public class PortletController {

 public PortletController() {
 }

 public String getUserName() {
  return "foobar";      
 }
}
```

My portlet tries to get the username, shown here:

```
public class ABPortlet extends MVCPortlet {

private String userName;

@EJB
PortletController controller;


public ABPortlet() {}

public void doView(RenderRequest rr, RenderResponse rp) throws IOException, PortletException {

    userName = controller.getUserName();
    if(userName==null) {
        userName = "nope";
    }
    rr.setAttribute("userName", userName);
    super.doView(rr, rp);
}
}
```

Have I already done something wrong? I read in a tutorial that i can access a local bean without lookup if the bean runs in the same JRE like the portlet.

How do i deploy both projects correctly? I exported the EJB project as jar and added it as dependency to the portlet project, but I just got a NullpointerException in the doView methode, at this line:

```
        userName = controller.getUserName();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I read in a tutorial that i can access a local bean without lookup if the bean runs in the same JRE like the portlet.

You meant in the same **JVM** when you mentioned the **JRE**, and yes that is right you don't have to bother about *JNDI* lookups if your portlet and ejb module runs both locally in the same JVM instance.

Regarding the way you packaged your application, I will advice not to do so (ejb and portlet in the same jar) because it is known from best practices that you would better separate your *business module* (ejb) from you *view module* (portlet).
So you may need to package each separately, the portlet goes to a war archive and your ejb to its own *jar*/module one.

Now going back to your code, you have some things to review following enterprise archive coding conventions:

Use a POJI to declare your local bean skeleton:

```
@Local
public interface PortletControllerLocal 
{
  public String getUserName();
}
```

Implement your `Stateless/Stateful` session bean and do specify its `name` annotation property:

```
@Statefull
@EJB(name = "portletControllerBean")
public class PortletControllerBean implements PortletConrollerLocal
{
  public String getUsername()
  {
    //Do you stuff
  }
}
```

Inject your bean under your portlet controller class with a `beanName` property:

```
public class ABPortlet extends MVCPortlet 
{
  private String userName;
  @EJB(beanName = "portletControllerBean")
  PortletControllerBean controller;

  public ABPortlet() {}

  public void doView(RenderRequest rr, RenderResponse rp) throws IOException,PortletException 
  {
    userName = controller.getUserName();
    if(userName==null) {
      userName = "nope";
    }
    rr.setAttribute("userName", userName);
    super.doView(rr, rp);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your anwser, it helps me a lot. Just one last question: When you say ejb's goes to "ejb/modules", you mean the folder /modules in my jboss home directory?

Comment: According to this manual I have to deploy the EJB's as an EAR file, edit the ejb-jar.xml to I dont know what and then i can use the EJB's without binding them into the java build path of my portlet?: [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/packaging002.htm#BCGFJIJI)

Comment: As far as I know, *ejb-jar.xml* is optional starting from EJB 3.0. Annotations are used instead to declare  EJBs metadata.
And as mentioned in the link you posted, you have either to package your module in a JAR (As I did advice to loose coupling between different layers) or inside your war file (it should be your portlet and it goes under *WEB-INF/classes*) and here you will have you EJBs strictly tied to your web application.